# Acer Nitro 5 brightness problem in 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: nvidia, brightness, acer

Screen is always in full brightness. The slider is visible and can be used, but it does not change the brightness of the screen. I installed the drivers that are on the official nvidia website, and I also tried other drivers but the problem continues. The software "brightness controller" and xrandr work. The function keys for brightness are recognized and change the slider, but have no effect. (I don't know if it's related but the camera isn't recognized either)
Model: Acer Nitro 5 AN515-58 with Intel Core I5 12500H and RTX 3050.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** According to this discussion on the [Acer community site](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/681690/backlight-and-web-camera-issue-on-acer-nitro-an515-58), you may want to check your version of BIOS that you're running.

Comment: Thanks. From what I've seen, I already have the latest version available. I noticed that the microphone is not working either. I installed ubuntu on dual boot with windows 11.

Comment: I have an Acer Nitro AN515-58, and this was the only thing that worked for me:
https://github.com/LarryTheMagicDragon/AcerAN515-58LinuxBrightnessBypass

Answer (score 0):

I did face the same problem, trying these may work (as it did for me).

You can try updating the kernel to version 6.0.0 (oem22.04b), atleast in my case it made my fn + left/right keys control brightness.

```
sudo apt install linux-oem-22.04b
```

Refer [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2000947) link where the webcam problem is discussed. Follow instructions to compile and replace the driver file.

The problem with this workaround(?) is that the webcam fix does not work with the kernel version where brightness control works. Atleast as far as I have seen

The brightness control also does not seem to work with any other kernel version (oem/generic) I have used, I don't know if there is any resolution to that

Comment: (Translated) Thanks. I tried this but didn't work unfortunately. After updating the kernel the function keys stopped "moving" the slider (previously an indication was displayed on the screen), so I restarted the computer and ubuntu did not start, so I reinstalled ubuntu (I don't know if that causes any problems, but it seems to be fine). Thanks anyway. I'll try installing some other kernel versions to see if that's the problem.

Comment: Made no difference for me either, Brightness control still does not work with kernel version 6.0.0.

Comment: @user392154 @rpaco can you try setting the kernel parameter to `acpi_backlight=video` ? You can do that by adding that text to your grub file in, and running `sudo update-grub`. Doing that fixed my brightness issue (at least hardware keys) in generic kernels too. Refer: askubuntu.com/a/19487/1706809 - how to add kernel parameters, and wiki.archlinux.org/title/backlight

Comment: I tried setting kernel parameters: acpi_backlight=video, acpi_backlight=vendor and acpi_backlight=native with no effect. I tried similar things changing /etc/default/grub but doesn't change anything or ubuntu doesn't start again. The recommended driver available in ubuntu repositories for my device (nvidia-driver-530) didn't work in the past and ubuntu didn't boot that time, but now it seems to be working.

Comment: Also "NVIDIA X Server Settings" program show less options in this version of the driver than in the nvidia-driver-525 version and i couldn't choose "Intel (Power Saving Mode)" in PRIME Profiles in any driver version.

Comment: 530 version doesn't show the graphics card in settings: "Mesa Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2) / Mesa Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2)" but 525 version does: "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU/Pcie/SSE2/ Mesa Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2)" and cannot choose between Wayland and Xorg in the start menu. (Also tried acpi_backlight=nvidia_wmi_ec in /etc/default/grub, didn't work)

Comment: @user392154 I will list everything I tried (afaik) to fix it on my AN515-58. If it still does not help, ig I'm out of my wit.
1. update the acer bios version to latest available (2.05)
2. install the `linux-oem-22.04b` kernel on a fresh install on ubuntu
3. installed Nvidia driver 525.116.04 (latest at that time and has a fix for backlight). I installed the run file from grub recovery menu. (make sure to remove all nvidia driver files before installing other versions, especially when using run files. Also check your installation with `nvidia-smi` if the correct 525 driver is installed

Comment: 4. Try setting this kernel parameter (and remove others) on 22.04b kernel `nvidia.NVreg_RegistryDwords=EnableBrightnessControl=1`. (and reboot and check)
5. at `/sys/class/backlight/` there should be at least folders like, acpi_video0, acpi_video1, acpi_video2, (other intel or nvidia folders there didn't change my brightness values). basically getting them appear solved my issue in other generic kernels 6. setting `acpi_backlight=video` solved it in generic kernels, while the kernel parameter in step 4 solved it for me initially in oem22.04b kernel. Or ig try checking any other driver works.

Comment: I tried linux-oem-22.04b alone (ubuntu started but didn't fix brightness, then tried "nvidia.NVreg_RegistryDwords=EnableBrightnessControl=1" which also didn't work) and with Nvidia driver 525.116.04 (but ubuntu didn't start). "acpi_backlight=video" didn't solved the problem before. I've noticed that in /sys/class/backlight/ there are no folders like "acpi_video0, acpi_video1, acpi_video2", just an intel and nvidia folders.

Answer (score 0):

**Open your terminal and paste below commands**

1. sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
2. **Replace**  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

**With**   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=native"

3. press ctrl+s , close the text editor
4. sudo update-grub

Then reboot your system.